# How to setLabelCount flexible depend on granularity

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

For example, I have line chart data like

```
YourData[] dataObjects = new YourData[4];
dataObjects[0] = new YourData(10,10);
dataObjects[1] = new YourData(11,11);
dataObjects[2] = new YourData(12,12);
dataObjects[3] = new YourData(15,15);
```

Currently, I want to display the granularity `0.5f`, so I use but it not working

```
YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
leftAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
leftAxis.setGranularity(0.5f);
```

[image]

Then I found that, if I `setLabelCount` with value **>= 11**, the `granularity` will work well

```
leftAxis.setLabelCount(11);
```

However, my data can change then the fixed value `11` may not work well. I see that the `granularity` still work well if we can set `labelCount` value greater than correct `labelCount` value (example 12,13,...).
And the maximum of `labelCount` in [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) is 25

```
public void setLabelCount(int count) {
    if (count > 25)
        count = 25;
    if (count < 2)
        count = 2;
    ...
}
```

Is it good if I always set `labelCount = 25` to make `granularity`
work? Or is there any flexible way to make `granularity` work? Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

[image]

Comment: can you help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58103744/mpandroidchart-x-axis-not-dislpay-all

Comment: @AI. sorry, long time I don't work with MPChart so I can not help you